# Subdivide all edges without creating new faces before applying wireframe modifier

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, wireframe

I'm trying to model an object with a curvature, smoothen the curvature and turn it into a triangular grid.
My current attempt is to triangulate, wireframe and then subdivide the object:

[image]

Unfortunately, the subsurf must be applied after wireframe which means that the curvature of the object itself is not smoothed like I wanted to. Its easy to see the sharp curve in the middle here:
[image]

My best attempt so far was to apply triangulation and manually subdivide the relevant edges:

[image]

Which did help:

[image]

But I need a more efficient way of doing this as the actual model I'm applying this to is much more complex. Additionally, the subdivision introduced artifacts making the wires oddly squashed. Ideally I would like them to be tubular.

Comment: maybe show a picture of the object you try to create?